# export a comma-separated string as a text file without auto-formatting it as a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, io

Im developing an API which should, ideally, export a conmma-separated list as a .txt file which should look like

`alphanumeric1, alphanumeric2, alphanumeric3`

the data to be exported is coming from a column of a pandas dataframe, so I guess I get it, but all my attempts to get it as a single-line string literal havent worked. Instead, the text file I receive is

```
,ColumnHeader
0,alphanumeric1
0,alphanumeric2
0,alphanumeric3
```

I've tried using string literals with the backticks, writing to multiple lines, appending commas to each value in the list, but it all comes out in the form of a csv, which wont work for my purposes.

How would yall achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if what you need is:

```
csvList = ','.join(df.ColumnHeader)
```

where, df is of course your pandas dataframe